# Position dialog in Android Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How to position dialog in Jetpack Compose to the bottom of the screen?

my real goal would be to place a dialog-like layout for the user (with a custom view) at the bottom of the screen and not centered like a regular dialog. with a background that darkens the back screen that
and one of the behaviors of a traditional dialog

here would be an example layout I'm trying to pass to compose.
[image: here would be an example layout I'm trying to pass to compose.]

Comment: Check the docs for [BottomSheetScaffold or BackdropScaffold](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#BottomSheetScaffold) - scroll down or search for `ModalBottomSheetLayout` or `BackdropScaffold`. That should position it at the bottom and give you the backdrop (darkened background). I would not recommend to use an iOS look & feel on the Android platform, but if you want to do that, then you can try to set the `sheetBackgroundColor` to transparent and add you composables inside with some padding.